# HTTP Error 414 - Requested URI is too long / base64 image

Tags: xml, jquery-mobile, base64, uri, http-error

I am trying to pull an base64 encoded image from a hosted XML file into my jQuery mobile app, but I get this error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 414
>   (Request-URI Too Long)

I know that for URLs, shortening them fixes the error but I can't shorten a base64 string.

Any ways around this?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question so I hope someone can benefit form my answer.

I just experienced this problem myself. I have gone through a few posts elsewhere and most of of what I read suggested you make sure your 64base string in your img src starts with data:image/;base64...

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,...">
```

Unfortunately that was not my issue. I was getting the (Request-URI Too Long) because my base64 had been JSON stringified so it looked something like this.

```
<img src=""data:image/gif;base64,..."">
```

Anyways, that's the two places I'd look for an error.